# How to estimate adsorption energy of Li atom on graphene?

Tags: vasp, adsorption

I would like to reproduce the data of adsorption energies published in [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apsusc.2017.12.046).

For example, they say the adsorption energy for Li atom on graphene is -1.19 eV (estimated by GGA-PBE). I used vasp (5.4) code using parameters indicated in the paper and estimated total energy for

Supercell 4x4x1 of graphene: `-0.29529545E+03 eV`;
Graphene with one Li atom on its surface: `-0.29635605E+03 eV`;
One Li atom (estimated from bcc structures): `-1.909 eV`.

Therefore, the adsorption energy should be `-296.35605 eV -[(-295.29545 eV) + (-1.909 eV)] = +0.848 eV`. It is inconsistent with the previous calculation.

If I use total energy for the isolated Li atom of `-0.29471258 eV`, the obtained adsorption energy is `-0.767 eV`. Both have a big gap with the published data. I wonder if there is a trick to accurately estimate the adsorption energy?

Comment: Hi, I edited your title to make it more clear. Feel free to roll back or re-edit if it doesn't fit what you are asking.

Comment: Does your optimized geometry match the literature one?

Comment: @wzkchem5, I  am sorry it is not matched. The result above is on top of C. At the hollow site, it should be  -1.104 eV using the total energy of the isolated  Li atom. But I don't know when  I should use the total energy of one Li atom estimated from bcc structures? And when I should use the total energy of an isolated Li atom?

Comment: Adsorption energies of atoms are defined with respect to isolated atoms, unless otherwise specified. I think you should first try to reproduce the literature geometry. If the geometry is wrong, you can never get the energy right.

Comment: @wzkchem5 You can correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you're able to answer the question in the Binh's latest comment, and in addition to that, your advice about first making sure the geometry is correct, is probably the best suggestion for the Binh given the amount of information we have. I would recommend that you combine those two pieces of advice into an *answer*. Then when Binh retries this with the correct geometry, if the adsorption energy is still wrong, the MMSE community can try to help them out at that time, when we know for sure that geometry was not the only problem.

Comment: @NikeDattani OK, I'll do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @NikeDattani's advice, now I rewrite my comments into an answer.

First of all, you should try to reproduce the geometry given in the paper. You mentioned in the comment that you got an adsorption energy of -1.104 eV at the hollow site, which is already quite close to the literature value of -1.19 eV. Does the adsorption geometry at the hollow site match the literature perfectly (not only qualitatively but also quantitatively, if you can assess their optimized atomic coordinates)? If the geometry still differs a little bit, then this may be the reason for the remaining discrepancy, for example whether you allowed your lattice constants to relax, whether you used the same slab width with the literature, etc.

As for whether you should use a single Li atom or bulk Li in calculating the adsorption energy, the answer is that unless otherwise specified, you should always use the energy of the single atom. That's how adsorption energy is defined.